# Sitecore user doesn't see menu buttons for fields like Image, Rich text, etc. in content tree

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Some user doesn't see menu buttons for fields like Image, Rich text, etc. in content tree. I mean Browse, Open media library, Show editor and other buttons above those fields of an item.

Everything is fine with security acccess to item field (user is able to edit), and to the each button. Moreover, renaming user login in database solve this problem, while renaming username back to original makes buttons to disappear again.

I used sitecore query to find any items that has security restriction for that user but nothing is found. I can create new user with the same roles set and buttons will be visible, but I need current user to be "as is" - it is on production.

Could you please suggest some ideas?

Comment: Has the user been configured with a different user language?  If so, that could make the Sitecore UI switch to a language for which there might be no translation, thus blanking out all the text (and therefore show no buttons)

Comment: The field options disappear when users have 'Raw Values' selected in the View tab. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @MarkCassidy, language is not an issue as we have all options the same when renaming user or create a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinDavies, no, Raw Values is not checked

Comment: The fact that you can rename the user to something else, and things work, indicates that it is a security problem of some sort. Sitecore stores security settings on field values. Try checking (on a database level) for field values containing the username in question. Something like SELECT * FROM [sc660rev140410Sitecore_core].[dbo].[SharedFields] WHERE [Value] LIKE '%your-user-name%'

Comment: @MarkCassidy , thank you for useful advice, but I already did so and 0 records found. I also tried to do this using sitecore query with the same result. Odd thing...

Comment: Have you tested to see if this happens on a clean install of Sitecore? Also, are you using any 3rd party authentication schemas?

Comment: How it can be reproduced on clean Sitecore? I need existing user to reproduce bug. I don't use any 3rd party auth schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I do not work on this project anymore and the problem remains unsolved I suppose that it was js error or strange behavior of js script related to admin console. We already had several issues with scripts, so I think it was the most likely trigger of that odd thing. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There could be problems with caching of AccessResult. By creation of new user you enforce Sitecore to re-evaluate all security rules and create new record in cache. Try to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
This seems to be an issue with Security. Follow these steps
Select Security tab for the media item. 
Select assign button.
Select add button.
Select by user and select the user for which the access is denied.
In permissions box give all accesses to that user.
```

Comment: As I mentioned in original question user is able to edit item